# Resolve shift/reduce conflict in Yacc/Bison grammar

Tags: bison, yacc

I am writing a parser in **GNU-Bison** to parse captured bits of data of a proprietary protocol. The parser has following tokens:

- `H` ....... Header
- `D` ....... Data
- `T` ....... Terminator

and five numbers of `D` i.e. Data tokens make up a ***bulk*** `B`
 i.e.

```
B : DDDDD
  ;
```

Ideally the input should be of the form

```
H DDDDD DDDDD DDDDD ... DDDDD T
```

aka

```
 H B B B ... B T
```

So I have written the following grammar :

```
%%
CAPTURE :  H PAYLOAD T     { printf("[OK]");}
        ;

PAYLOAD :  B
        |  PAYLOAD B
        ;

B       :  DDDDDD
%%
```

Now, to meet some practical conditions such as a pattern like following:

1. `DD H DDDDD DDDDD ... DDDDD T`    (extra D's at the prefix)
2. `H DDDDD DDDDD ... DDD T` (truncated last ***bulk*** having just 3 Data `D`)

I modified my grammar to

```
%%
CAPTURE :  H PAYLOAD T     { printf("[OK]");}
        ;

PAYLOAD :  B
        |  PAYLOAD B
        |  D PAYLOAD
        |  PAYLOAD D
        ;

B       :  DDDDDD
%%
```

But It is giving `shift/reduce conflict`. 
  Need help how to correct the grammar so that it recognises above two cases also and is shift/reduce conflict free.

Comment: This is terrible overkill. You don't need Bison for this.

Comment: Maybe its an overkill, but I feel its just quicker to write a small grammar in yacc than writing a program from scratch for lexing and parsing even for a trivial syntax and grammar.

Comment: It usually is quicker provided you don't get stuck :-p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
%%
CAPTURE : OPTD1 H PAYLOAD OPTD2 T     { printf("[OK]");}
        ;

PAYLOAD :  B
        |  PAYLOAD B
        ;

B       :  D D D D D
        ;

OPTD1   :
        |  OPTD1 D
        ;

OPTD2   :
        |  D D D
        ;
%%
```

I added two new non-terminals `OPTD1` and `OPTD2` on the right-hand side of the first production and kept your original rule for `PAYLOAD` as it was. `OPTD1` can be rewritten as 0 or more `D` terminal symbols and `OPTD2` can be rewritten as 0 or 3 `D` terminal symbols.

If your TOKENS, H, T and B were just the characters 'H', 'T' and 'B' respectively, you could easily recognize valid input with the following regular expression:

```
'^D*H(DDDDD)+(DDD)?T$'
```

In any event, you should be able to recognize valid input with a finite state automaton with the power of a pushdown automaton provided by YACC not being required.